Who built Colony 6's ether mine? And when?
I used to assume the ether mine below Colony 6 was originally built by the inhabitants of Colony 6, i.e. Homs. But when running through the installation, I noticed the design of the apparatuses.
(The remainder of the question contains heavy spoilers that will ruin Xenoblade Chronicles.)
If one disregards the rock it looks very Mechon, which no other Bionis architecture does. Specifically it reminds me of Mechonis Field and Central Factory. Additionally, Sharla initially claims the Mechon will have a hard time figuring out the maze that is the mine, but when arriving in the mine proper, the Mechon indeed have spread through the entire mine and know exactly how to operate the machinery.

This makes me think the mine could have been a joint project before the falling out between Egil and Arglas. Probably predating the existence of Homs entirely. And much later the Homs who came to settle Colony 6 just found the machinery and claimed the place as their own.
Alternatively, the Homs could have been mining the place with less sophisticated instruments and the Mechon actually built the huge drill in the middle of the mine during the most recent occupation. But it is doubtful whether they could have built all this in such short time. I don't know exactly how much time passed between the occupation of Colony 6 and Shulk's party entering the mine, though. Days or weeks?
Any other, unrelated time frame?

In addition to the mine itself, the dome above the Homs colony also looks vaguely Mechon in design. It could have been built at the same time or independently from the mine. The Mechon do not seem to attribute any military value to the colony proper, given that Juju and Otharon waltz in there by themselves and start rebuilding it.
So, who built the equipment inside the ether mine, when and why?
